# Clearing an object properly "getters should not be used for side effects"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, xcode4

I am following the well known Stanford online course in Objective C.

The course builds on a RPN calculator built using Model:View:Controller
I have to create a clear button which I have using the following code (which works) into the View controller

`self.display.text=@"0";`

`self.display.history=@"";`

`self.brain.clear;`

in the model (referred to by the object "brain") the only instance variable is a NSMutableArray with the various things entered by the calculator user in it.

I have put a method called "clear" into the model that clears the array using the removeAllObjects method.

I am getting a warning from Xcode that 
 "property access unused getters should not be used for side effects"

I have tried just deleting the brain object using lines like

self.brain dealloc; to no avail.

How should I clear down the brain object correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
[self.brain clear]; // <-- Calls method 'clear' of object brain
```

instead of

```
self.brain.clear; // <-- Access property 'clear' of object brain
```

**When you need to call a method you should use the bracket "[" , "]" notation.**

*[object method];*

e.g: *[human setAge:12]*;

**When you need to access a property of the object you should use the dot notation.**

*object.propery;*

e.g: *age = human.age;*

Comment: Hey, almost! I needed '[self.brain clear]' Could someone clarify the difference between 'self.brain.clear' and '[self.brain clear]' for me? I suspect I am being confused by my java experience.

Comment: Yeah I know. Thats what i suggested to change

Comment: why does `self.brain.clear` work but generate a warning, `[self.brain.clear]` fail to build and `[self.brain clear]` work without warning? [Insufficient rep to promote your answer but thanks]

Comment: The bracket notation should always contain 2 expressions separated by a space. Thats why [self.brain.clear] fails to build

Comment: [brain clear] is equivalent to brain.Clear() and brain.clear is equivalent to brain.clear in java

Comment: In (part) answer to my own question `[self.brain clear]`; in Obj C is like `self.brain.clear()`; in java. whereas `something=self.brain.clear` (Obj C) is like something = `self.brain.getClear();` would be in java?

Comment: No. self.brain.getClear is a getter method, not a property. The obj-C equivalent is [self.brain size]. The default setters in obj-C is [object size] and the setter is [object setSize:15]; Please accept the answer for the future users.